# React: mocking http calls for local development

Tags: reactjs

I have a React components package that is published to NPM registry an later on consumed by other components.

In this package I have a container component that uses some services to make HTTP calls. Currently it uses them by importing them:

```js
import { fetchData } from '../../services'
...
async componentDidMount() {
  const data = await fetchData(params);
}
```

For local development I have an app that hosts this component, however it can’t make real HTTP calls because it lacks context (authentication headers etc.).

I’d like to feed the component with some data and I’m wondering what is the best way to do that?

I see two alternatives:

- Use [nock](https://github.com/nock/nock) and mock the http calls in the host application
- Pass the `fetchData` on props instead of importing it and then pass a dummy function from the Root app component.

Which one should I choose and why? Are there any other alternatives?

***Important***: I'm not talking about testing (the component is tested with Jest and all the services are mocked) but rather about local development.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can just import your mocked response from local repo?

```
import mock from './file.json';

const fetch = (fetchUri) => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
      return this.fetchDataMock();
    }
    return this.fetchData();
  }

const fetchDataMock = () => {
    return Promise.resolve(mock);
}
```

You can use `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'` to determine your environment.

Comment: How do you propose to use `fetchMock` instead of `fetchData`? Just replacing it for development? That's not an option as I'd like to keep my component untouched.

Comment: @meltedspark if statement? To check If you are in development

Comment: If statement where? Inside the service? It would be a development specific code in production, which is considered a very bad practice.